# Evopdf truncate contains in pdf

Tags: evopdf

I use evaluation version of evopdf.
Actually, evopdf truncate contains in the render pdf document.
I think that evopdf only render the part of document visible in window browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is your HTML content inside a scrolling area? In this case you have to either create a version of the HTML which displays the entire content inside the scrolling area or set a large custom viewer height in HtmToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerHeight .

For example:

```
// Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

// Set HTML viewer height in pixels to convert the top part of a HTML page 
// Leave it not set to convert the entire HTML
htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerHeight = 2000;
```

You can also find the working example with C# source code at http://www.evopdf.com/demo/ where you can test online your HTML page.